# Marshmallow nested serialization of a list with base class schema to honour the subclassed schema classes

Tags: python, abstract-class, marshmallow, python-dataclasses

I am using `marshmallow-dataclass` to build serializable classes, and nest them under another class in a list.

There is a `Base` dataclass, which is an abstract class, and has majority of functionality implemented, as well as having `@abcmethod`s. From the base, other dataclasses are created; there will be multiple variations, all subclassed from the `Base`. Those subclasses work well on their own.

I intend to append all instanced to a `Store` dataclass under `.items`. Then be able to have it serialized and deserialized.

Below is a simplified version of what I have:

```py
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
from typing import List, Tuple
import marshmallow_dataclass
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Base(ABC):
    name: str
    # _klass: str = None

@marshmallow_dataclass.dataclass
class NameAge(Base):
    age: int

@marshmallow_dataclass.dataclass
class NameLocation(Base):
    loc: Tuple[float, float]

@marshmallow_dataclass.dataclass
class Store:
    items: List[Base]
```

Here is an example of intended use:

```py
a1 = NameAge('John', 33)
a2 = NameLocation('Bob', (50.8, -0.1))

store = Store(items=[a1, a2])

payload = Store.Schema().dump(store)

store_again = Store.Schema().load(payload)

# desired outcome
assert store == store_again
```

**The Problem**

- When loading/dumping a `Store` instance, the `Base` class schema is used for `.items`.
  The `Base` is declared as the type in the List, thus the base is used to build the `.Schema()` as the serializer.
  However, the desired behaviour is for each instance to be (de-)serialzed its dedicated class.

**What I tried so far**

- The dataclass attribute `_klass` to serialize and track which class is used, so the right serializer can be built.
- Tried creating a base schema (as in `@marshmallow_dataclass.dataclass(base_schema=BaseSchema)`), trying to intercept with `@pre_dump` and `@pre_load`, but without much success.
- Tried intercepting with a constructor `Base.__new__` in order to return the right schema class, however it seemed it was not called at deserialization stage.

Any suggestions or help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Schemas are not inherited: how would the deserialisation know about a class's child classes? Instead use `typing.Union`:

```py
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
from typing import List, Tuple, Union

...

@marshmallow_dataclass.dataclass
class Store:
    items: List[Union[NameAge, NameLocation]]
```

You'll need to install the `union` extra: `pip install marchmallow-dataclass[union]`